# How to move data files (oradata) from corrupted Oracle's11g new Oracle 11g?

Tags: database, oracle11g, restore

I am using Oracle version 11g and Oracle Linux 6.5 . But Oracle 11g damaged.
How to move data files (oradata) from old corrupted Oracle's11g in new Oracle 11g and startup database ?????

Comment: Is you database corrupted or Oracle binaries corrupted?

Comment: What is current location of datafiles, controlfiles and redologs? Do you want these files to move ?

Comment: @SwapnilBoralkar  yes. move(datafiles, controlfiles and redologs).

Comment: @SwapnilBoralkar I am using Oracle Linux 6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Create Pfile from spfile ( This step is not needed if DB is already running on pfile)

```
sqlplus "/as sysdba"
create pfile from spfile;
```

2) Shutdown database

```
sqlplus "/as sysdba"
shu immediate;
```

3) Move pfile and password file  from old $ORACLE_HOME/dbs to new $ORACLE_HOME/database (this is Windows specific, if you are using unix/linux folder is dbs instead of database)

4) Edit pfile and replace controlfile parameter with new location.

5) set New oracle_home parameter and path location

6) Login to sqlplus and create spfile from pfile.

```
sqlplus "/as sysdba"
create spfile from pfile;
```

7) Follow below link to change file location in control file.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dfiles005.htm#ADMIN11431

8) Open database.
alter database open.

Comment: Do not have video training (oracle linux 6.5) ?